# Why is the logging message displayed after the input message?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems that the input function is displaying the message before the logging message. Why could this be happening?

```
import configparser
from pathlib import Path
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('test')
log.debug('Current directory: {}'.format(Path().absolute()) )
filename = input('load ini from > ')
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(filename)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try: ```handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout);
log.addHandler(handler)```

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue.  With log.debug nothing is printed (default level is warning). With log.warning the logging message comes before the input.